# Отправить post запрос с переходом на искомую страницу

Tags: php, post

Как отправить post запрос на определенный url, чтобы вместе с отправленным запросом пользователь оказался на странице, на которую запрос был послан?

Пока есть такой код:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'shopId' => $user->Shop->shop_id,
        'scid' => $user->Shop->sc_id,

        'CustomerNumber' => $user->id,
        'sum' => $pay->sum,

        'orderNumber' => $pay->id,
        'cps_phone' => '79110000000',
        'cps_email' => 'user@domain.com',

        'paymentType' => $_POST['paymentType'],

//      //PC - Со счета в Яндекс.Деньгах (яндекс кошелек)
//      'paymentType' => 'PC',
//      //AC - С банковской карты
//      'paymentType' => 'AC',

    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
//      'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Этот код, предположительно, работает))

Только он получает ответ в переменную `$results`, а нужно чтобы пользователь отправлялся на эту страницу вместе с запросом.

Comment: Ну так если пользователь должен вместе с запросом туда идти, то это надо на стороне клиента делать, а не на стороне сервера. На сервере вы можете либо сгенерировать форму с нужными значениями, показать эту форму клиенту и засабмитить эту форму сразу же, либо возвращать клиенту сгенерированный url, на который он будет перенаправлен, но тогда будет не post, а get-запрос

Comment: @BOPOH Толково. Оформите в виде ответа.

Comment: @BOPOH
Спасибо, я сначала совсем не сообразил что раз это должен видеть клиент, значит это на его стороне должно происходить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. создать форму, заполненную пришедшими POST-данными;
2. JavaScript'ом отправлять эту форму с посетителем на конечный сайт.

Примерный php:

```
$url = 'http://ya.ru'; // ссылка, куда надо сделать POST запрос
$dataFields = array(   // ассоц. массив данных, которые нужно передать
    'shopId' => $user->Shop->shop_id,
    'scid' => $user->Shop->sc_id,
);

$html = sprintf( '<form name="formPost" id="formPost" action="%s" method="post">', $url);
foreach( $dataFields AS $key=>$value) {
    $html .= sprintf( '<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s">',
        $key, $value);
}
$html .= '</form>';
```

И добавить отправку сразу, или по событию UI. Что-то типа:

```
$html .= <<<EOFJS
<script>
    document.formPost.submit();
</script>
EOFJS;

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax-ом можно реализовать.

```
    <form target="_blank" action="https://demomoney.yandex.ru/eshop.xml" style="border:1px solid #c2c2c2; padding:20px 15px;" name='paymentForm' method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="shopId" value="XXXXXXX">
                <input type="hidden" name="scid" value="XXXXXXXx">
                <input type="hidden" name="customerNumber" value="XXXXXXX">
                <input type="hidden" name="payTime" value="<?= time(); ?>">

                <label>Способ оплаты</label>
                <select name="paymentType">
                    <option value="PC" selected="selected">Оплата из кошелька в Яндекс.Деньгах</option>
                    <option value="AC">Оплата с произвольной банковской карты</option>
                    <option value="MC">Оплата со счета мобильного телефона</option>
                    <option value="GP">Оплата наличными через кассы и терминалы</option>
                    <option value="WM">Оплата из кошелька в системе WebMoney</option>
                    <option value="SB">Оплата через Сбербанк: по смс или Сбербанк Онлайн</option>
                    <option value="MP">Оплата через мобильный терминал (mPOS)</option>
                    <option value="AB">Оплата через Альфа-Клик</option>
                    <option value="MA">Оплата через MasterPass</option>
                    <option value="PB">Оплата через интернет-банк Промсвязьбанка</option>
                    <option value="QW">Оплата через QIWI Wallet</option>
                    <option value="KV">Оплата через КупиВкредит (Тинькофф Банк)</option>
                    <option value="QP">Оплата через Доверительный платеж на Куппи.ру</option>
                </select>
                <label>Цена</label>
                <input type="text" name="sum">
                <br>
                <div id="pay" class="btn btn-success" >Оплатить</div>
            </form>
```

Сам jQuery:

```
    <script>
    (function ($) {
    /*
     * Делаем глобально, для того чтобы переменная была доступна для callback функции
     */
form = $('form[name=paymentForm]');

$('#pay', form).click(function () {

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/saveData.php/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responce){
            if(!responce.error){

                /*
                 * Если данные сохранены успешно отправляем форму с перенаправлением на целевую страницу
                 * в данном случае https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml
                 */
                form.submit();
            }else{
                alert(responce.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

В обработчике saveData.php

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST)){
        //сохранение в БД
    }
    //после сохранения в БД возвращаете ответ так

    echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'msg' => 'Данные сохранены'));
    //или
   echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'Данные не сохранены'));

    ?>
```

Проверено лично мной. Работает)